# One-liner for checking if integer is of form 2^1-2^j using bitwise operators

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want a one line code to check whether a given integer is of form 2<sup>i</sup> - 2<sup>j</sup> or NOT. (using bitwise operators)

Comment: A direct answer can be found in "Hacker's Delight" :)

Comment: Smells like homework. How far did you get?

Comment: @sbi : Can't you read the tags? (Homework)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As AndreyT says, the answer can be found in [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/basics.pdf):

> Use the following formula to turn off the rightmost contiguous string of 1-bits (e.g., 01011000 ⇒ 01000000):
>
> ```
> ((x | (x – 1)) + 1) & x
> ```
>
> This may be used to see if a nonnegative integer is of the form 2<sup>*j*</sup> – 2<sup>*k*</sup> for some *j* ≥ *k* ≥ 0; apply the formula followed by a 0-test of the result.

(was debating whether to post this, as it's a homework question, but as AndreyT already mentioned it and it's easily Googlable, I figure it's more helpful to quote directly; I'll let the questioner deal with the ethical implications of accepting help on the homework, and I expect that if his answer depends on this, he will write up the explanation of how it works himself)

Answer (score 1):

A hint or two:

Other have pointed out that what you're looking for is a number that consists of a string of ones followed by a string of zeros.

If you flip all the bits in this, you'll get a string of 0's followed by a string of 1's. If you increment that, all the one bits will become zeros, and exactly one bit above those will become a one.

If you AND those last two together, you'll get zero.

Answer (score 0):

In binary, a power of two is a number of the form `100...0` (A `1` followed by `x` `0`s, where `x` is the exponent)

Therefore, any binary number of the form 2<sup>i</sup> - 2<sup>j</sup> will be a string of `1`s followed by a string of `0`s.

Windows Calculator (in binary mode) is a great way to experiment with this.

Comment: I know that its's 1s followed by 0s. What I am not able to figure out is how to test that with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this for a moment.  If i=j, then the answer is checking to see if the integer is 0.  Otherwise, the key is to see how often the bits toggle I think as what you want to see is if all the 1s are together as a group, collectively, as really the arithmetic here is quite simple.  If the toggle is 2 then it is of that form.

Answer (score 0):

Left shift until you get a 0, once u get a zero, u should not get 1 again

Comment: "Left shift until" - Even this is not possible to do in one line.

Comment: And my point was about "shift until" because that involves repeating a certain action until a certain condition is true and this is not possible to do in one line. Changing "right" to "left" makes no difference as such.

Comment: Thats why i said in my second comment that its my mistake, the solution i suggested is not a one liner.